# Unreadable barplot y-axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dt.csv with two columns and thousands of rows, that looks like this:

```
mea_mg_kg_derived;class
0.1;Actinopterygii
1.2;Actinopterygii
0.8;Elasmobranchii
2.1;Malacostraca
1.1;Elasmobranchii
0.5;Malacostraca
```

The values in "mea_mg_kg_derived" column go from 1.670e -6 to 61, and this column includes missing values (NA).

What I'm trying to do is to plot the group means of mea_mg_kg_derived (the mean of mea_mg_kg_derived, calculated for every single group of class, e.g. Actinopterygii, Elasmobranchii, Malacostraca...).

I've tried with this on R-Studio:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=factor(class), y=mea_mg_kg_derived)) + stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="bar")
```

and this is the output:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the y-axis?

Comment: The variable you are using for your y axis is non-numeric. Presumably it's a factor or character at the moment. Check `class(dt$mea_mg_kg_derived)`. Are there perhaps commas in the numbers which are forcing the conversion to character? In any case, you need to convert these to actual numbers to get a sensible y axis

Comment: @Allan Cameron, I've tried with class(dt$mea_mg_kg_derived), and it gives me "factor". I don't know what to do. There are no commas in mea_mg_kg_derived column. The decimal separator is full stop.

Comment: Try `dt$mea_mg_kg_derived <- as.numeric(as.character(dt$mea_mg_kg_derived))` and repeat your plot

Comment: yeah! now it works. Thank you!